# Difference between 'Recordset Rs, SQL, Conn' and 'Rs.open SQL,Conn,1'

Tags: sql, asp-classic, connection, recordset

In ASP,
What is the difference between 'Recordset Rs, SQL, Conn' and 'Rs.open SQL,Conn,1'?

and 'Rs.open SQL, Conn, 1' --> '1' What are the roles

Comment: `RecordSet` usually a class defining the required SQL for your needs, that holds a connection to the database. `rs` will normally be the variable that holds the reference to the RecordSet object. SQL is SQL (what can I say?), most likely a string of SQL syntax. `Conn` will either be a string containing the connection string or possibly the connection object itself. `Rs.Open SQl, Conn, 1` - the roles are associated on the SQL server side to the account in the connection string.

Comment: @Paul I wouldn't have even have bothered trying to comment / answer this question in it's current form.

Comment: I know, but hopefully they'll take something away from it and start doing their own research.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking what the difference is between

```
Rs.Open SQL,Conn,1
```

and

```
Rs.Open SQL,Conn
```

i.e. you want to know what that "1" is. The answer to that can be found in the [documentation for the ADO Recordset Open method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

> Syntax:
>   `recordset.Open Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options`

The third parameter is the CursorType.

> Optional. A [CursorTypeEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value that determines the type of cursor that the provider should use when opening the **Recordset**. The default value is **adOpenForwardOnly**.

If you click the link for CursorTypeEnum, you'll find a table listing all the possible values for this parameter. The table says that 1 is **adOpenKeyset**:

> Uses a keyset cursor. Like a dynamic cursor, except that you can't see records that other users add, although records that other users delete are inaccessible from your **Recordset**. Data changes by other users are still visible.

Compare that to the default value, **adOpenForwardOnly**:

> Default. Uses a forward-only cursor. Identical to a static cursor, except that you can only scroll forward through records. This improves performance when you need to make only one pass through a **Recordset**.

So, if you're only reading the data, and only going through it once, you can use the default value. If you need to make any changes to the data, and/or if you need to move back and forth in the records, then you'll need to add the extra parameter. (You can look through the CursorTypeEnum values to see if another CursorType might be suitable, but I'll tell you that in practice, 1 and 0 will cover 99.99% of cases.)